# Python and Pandas - Transferring Excel formula to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, weibull

At the moment, I'm trying to migrate my Weibull calculations from an excel macro to Python, and the tool I've been primarily using is Pandas. The formula I am currently having trouble converting from excel to Python is as follows:

Adjusted Rank = (Previous value in the adjusted rank column) * (Another column's value), but the first value in the adjusted rank column = 0

My brain is trying to copy and paste this methodology to pandas, but as you can imagine, it doesn't work that way:

DF[Adjusted Rank] = (Previous value in the adjusted rank column) * DF(Another Column), but the first value in the adjusted rank column = 0

In the end, I imagine the adjusted rank column will look like so:

```
                     Adjusted Rank
                           0
                       Some Number
                       Some Number
                       Some Number
                       etc.
```

I'm having some trouble puzzling out how to make each "cell" in the adjusted rank column refer to the previous value in the column In Pandas. Additionally, Is there a way to set only the first entry in the column equal to 0? Thanks all!

Comment: Don't forget now you can vote! good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shift to multiply by previous values and add a zero to the start, this should work:

```
   df['new'] = df['adjusted_rank'].shift(period = 1, fill_value=0) * df['another_column']
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot!